# Custom Angular component doesn't get rendered as TR in the template

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table

I'm redesigning a table and I wanted to introduce my own, custom components instead of the default TR element. The table works as supposed to and looks like this.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th *ngFor="let column of this.columns">{{column.title}}</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of this.rows"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then, I introduced my own component to substitute the usual TR and switched the markup of the grid to the following.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th *ngFor="let column of this.columns">{{column.title}}</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <row *ngFor="let row of this.rows" [value]="row" [formats]="columns"></row>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The markup of the new component is very rudimentary as shown below.

```
<td *ngFor="let format of formats">
  {{value[format.id]}}
</td>
```

It works, kind of. I.e. I can see the values **but** al the TDs generated (which I can confirm checking the devtools) get rendered in the first column of the table. So the data binding works. The generation of the markup works. The only thing that fails is that the stupid browser doesn't get that ROW is supposed to the a row (like TR is). It thinks that it can be rendered as a single TD.

How do I tell the stupid browser to do what I meant, not what I said?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is because it doesn't recognize `row` as a `tr` and therefore it doesn't render properly the `table`.

Try using your component like this:

```
@Component({ 
   selector: '[row]',
   template: `
   <td *ngFor="let format of formats">
      {{value[format.id]}}
   </td>
   ` 
})
```

And then in your table:

```
<tr row></tr>
```

This way, *everyone* recognizes the `tr` as a `tr` but it will behave like you want to: using your `row` component.

*(I had the same problem with a custom menu element. It didn't recognize the `li` element. Using `<li my-element>` fixed the issue.)*

Comment: _"This is called Attribute directive"_ No, it's not. Why would you call a component something else, just because the selector changed?

Comment: @zeroflagL Indeed, after reading your comment I realized that I just changed the way the component is invoked, I did not use `@Directive` that would have made an actual **Attribute directive**. His component is still a component because it uses `@Component` even though it gets invoked as if it was a directive. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @zeroflagL Are you saying that the suggestion is flawed? I don't really dare to tell, based on my level of confusion at the moment. I accepted the reply because it worked out - the columns are rendered as supposed to now. However, I fear that I'm learning the wrong pattern (also, leaving a trace for future users that they might rely on and keep to err). What do you think?

Comment: @KonradViltersten No, is that I wrote *"This is called Attribute directive"*, and that was not correct and he pointed it out and I deleted it from my answer. Why it's not correct that statement I explain in my previous comment. It's a common practice to *invoke* a component as an attribute if you want to maintain the HTML tag intact. So, don't worry about that. Just realize that by invoking your component like if it was a directive doesn't make it an **Attribute directive**: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html